# How to save jimp resized image to mongoDb database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, file-upload

how to save the image jimp resized to MongoDB database. I am using nodejs, express, multer and gridfs. The write method writes to a folder only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for one, you shouldn't do it unless you really know what you're doing. You're better off using local storage, or an S3 bucket.

However, if you *really* want to do it, you can base64 encode your image.

```
Jimp.read(...).then(function(img) {
    // manipulate your image
    img.getBase64(Jimp.AUTO, (err, base64Image) => {
        // save base64Image to database
    })
});
```

Then on the client side output it as:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, "+base64Image />
```

Comment: I want to save the image after resizing, not the buffer (it is too large!)

Comment: and how to save the png or jpg file to MongoDB database

Comment: You save the base64 encoded image, not the image itself. Save it as a regular entry.Yes, images are usually quite large and they shouldn't be saved in the database. You also lose the ability to stream images which reduces load times.

Comment: I want to save the image not the buffer is it possible and I am not interested in saving buffer

Comment: I am using multer to save the image first time then resizing it then saving the resized image to the database I am able to save the resized image in a folder through jimp.write but I want to save it in the database if you know multer also can you tell how to save the resized image to database and delete the image in the folder

Comment: You don't need to save a temporary image, just return the base64 encoded image and save it as a regular string. Buffer contains the image data that you encode.

Comment: but I need the image as the buffer is heavier than the image

Comment: Please, read more about buffers and what they are, because I feel you are looking at them the wrong way. At the end of the day, you shouldn't store images in a database.

Comment: will the buffers be different if we upload the same file two times

Comment: No, buffers should be exactly the same.

Comment: can jimp take file from input               <input type="file" name="file" accept=".jpg , .png, .jpe" id="file" class="custom-file-input" onchange="myFunction()">  I am using body-parser

Comment: Read about handling file upload in node.js. That's where you use Jimp.

Comment: Technically you can process images in the browser using Jimp, but it requires a different implementation. Since browsers can't access local filesystem due to security concerns, you first upload images to the server, return a list of image urls, process each image in the browser, and send them back to the server. `Jimp.read({ url }).then(image => { //process image }).then(image => { //upload processed image })`